# Regex in Perl for filtering Webmin log

Tags: regex, perl

I need to filter the following line from secure log only matching `webmin` and `Invalid login as root from` using Perl regex:

`Apr  2 00:24:53 host webmin[98614]: Invalid login as root from 1.2.3.4`

I tried this but it fails to match:

`$line =~ /^\S+\s+\d+\s+\S+ \S+ webmin[\]: \Invalid login as root from/)`

What am I missing here?

Comment: **What does "fails" mean?** "Fails" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Andy, I use this `regex` as a part of log filtering for Firewall written in Perl! I can't really say what failed! The event wasn't caught, that's it!

Comment: @Andy Lester, fails to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `[` is the start of the character class. You want to match that literally, so you need to escape it.
- You never match the `98614` part.
- The `\I` should simply be `I`. `\I` will even give you a warning.

```
/^\S+\s+\d+\s+\S+ \S+ webmin\[\d+\]: Invalid login as root from/
```

Comment: Thank you ikegami but it seems I need more of your help? Please check (I'm not Perl guy at all, sorry): http://codepad.org/umCAchCZ

Comment: You added `m{` and `}`, so you're now trying to match a literal `/` at two spots. If you want to use `m{...}` instead of `/.../`, don't keep the `/`!

Comment: @Andy Lеster, everything was corrected referring to my question and ikegami answer works the correct way! As an example, I prefer to post working examples, on external sites just because StackOverflow doesn't have such functionality. The question and the answer self-reliant and external example was made just for future readers! What exactly you don't like about my question, tell us in plain words and I'll fix it!?

Comment: I don't know what "such functionality" you refer to could be.  You can edit your question and repost the corrected question and not have to use an external site.

Comment: @Andy Lester, the posted answer is for the posted question. That a second question and answer is present in the comments doesn't mean the existing question and answer should be edited.

Comment: @ikegami Could you please tell me how to match `TCP_DENIED/407` from `1392714132.861 0 1.2.3.4 TCP_DENIED/407 3922 CONNECT google.com:443 username HIER_NONE/- text/html`. I tried different ways but it's not matching? (this is Squid log line)

Comment: @Ilia Rostovtsev, `(split ' ')[3]`. I suppose there's also `/^(?:\S+\s+){3}(\S+)/`

Comment: @ikegami thanks for your reply but I am not sure I understood what you mean about splitting?

Comment: That code does what you asked. Uses `$_` by default (like the match operator I also provided), but you can specify a different variable as a second argument.

Comment: @ikegami Your regular expression matches, example: http://regex101.com/r/tG7kJ5.
The point is not just to get `TCP_DENIED/407` but to validate the log file line. In case a log file will contain `.... TCP_DENIED/407 ... ` more that 3 times, the IP will be blocked.. My point is to detect `TCP_DENIED/407` in a line..

Comment: The problem with asking questions in the comments is that they usually aren't thought out or incomplete. Please use the proper process for asking a question.

Comment: You're are right! I just came up with this example, http://regex101.com/r/jC8aE7. Thank you for your help.